# Autolayout: Custom UIView height constraint with UIWebViews

Tags: ios, uiview, uiwebview, constraints, autolayout

i am building a Custom UIView with two UIWebViews with variable heights inside and some Labels.

I build the View with a xib File. In this Xib the View has a height of 500(but it can be greater depending on the content of the WebView)

Now i have the problem that i add two or more from my custom UIViews programmatically to my UIViewController inside a scrollview. But they are not among each other!

My custom views will be displayed right but don't have the right height constraint and so one is above each other and not below each other...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code snippet.

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSString *webHeight = [self.lblDetail stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.height"];
    NSLog(@"height: %@", webHeight);

    self.webViewHeightConstraint.constant = [webHeight intValue]; 
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty new to autolayout, can you explain where self.webViewHeightConstraint is coming from?

Comment: it is the height constraint of the webview which comes from storyboard. I found height of the webview from storyboard and link it to the class that i use in. i name it "webViewHeightConstraint", it is simply height constraint of webView.